# what is conversion system of LM35 (temperature sensor) in Celsius?

Tags: arduino, sensors

I see formula like

```
temp = (5*val*100/1024)
```

Can anyone tell me the details of this formula?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the truth *always* lies within the datasheets:

- http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf on how to get the data from the LM35 ;
- http://atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf on how to use the Atmega ADC.

#### The Atmega ADC: Analog to Digital Converter

Your Atmega is powered by 5V, and the datasheet of the Atmega states that its ADC has a definition of 1024 values (i.e. 10bits). So in your formula, `5/1024` is representing each voltage step represented by a bit:

```
0.0000V -> 0b0000000000
0.0048V -> 0b0000000001
...
5.0000V -> 0b1000000000
```

#### Getting value out of the LM35

If you read the application notes in the LM35 datasheet, you'll find the following formula:

```
Vout=10mV/°C
```

if you're binding the LM35 with a 200ohms resistor. So if you use the rule of three, you'll get:

```
Vout=0.01/°C
°C=Vout/0.01
°C=Vout/0.01
°C=Vout*100
```

HTH

Comment: why there is 11 bit for voltage representation? :@zmo

Comment: because it should be 8 bits, it's been a typo when I wrote my answer :-)

Comment: thanks to a rejected edit, just noticed that I was wrong: this is indeed 10bits, as the datasheet specs it, and the voltage representation is on 10 bits. Aside from that detail, what I say stays right.

Answer (score 1):

for Arduinos;

```
val = analogRead(tempPin);

float mv = ( val/1024.0)*5000; 

float cel = mv/10;
```